# External Hard Drive is Recognize, but can not be Opened

Tags: hard-drive, external-hdd, drive

I connected my external Hard Drive to my machine. It was recognized but it could not opened. I rund `dmesg` command and this is what I got:

```
[  571.197590] usb 2-7: New USB device found, idVendor=0bc2, idProduct=231a
[  571.197595] usb 2-7: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  571.197598] usb 2-7: Product: Expansion
[  571.197602] usb 2-7: Manufacturer: Seagate
[  571.197604] usb 2-7: SerialNumber: NA8G0H3A
[  571.204442] scsi host2: uas
[  571.205361] scsi 2:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Seagate  Expansion        0707 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[  571.206683] sd 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[  574.382577] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] 1953525167 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/932 GiB)
[  574.382582] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] 4096-byte physical blocks
[  574.382729] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[  574.382733] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 53 00 00 08
[  574.383038] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[  574.383309] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Optimal transfer size 33553920 bytes not a multiple of physical block size (4096 bytes)
[  574.416860]  sdc: sdc1
[  574.418657] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
[  609.286301] audit: type=1400 audit(1592360174.948:90): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/sssd" name="/etc/krb5.conf.d/" pid=1347 comm="sssd_be" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[  617.314396] audit: type=1400 audit(1592360182.982:91): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/sssd" name="/etc/krb5.conf.d/" pid=1347 comm="sssd_be" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[  752.033073] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 uas_zap_pending 0 uas-tag 1 inflight: CMD 
[  752.033081] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 74 70 59 00 00 00 08 00
[  752.033089] sd 2:0:0:0: tag#1 uas_zap_pending 0 uas-tag 2 inflight: CMD 
[  752.033093] sd 2:0:0:0: tag#1 CDB: Test Unit Ready 00 00 00 00 00 00
[  752.033138] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  752.033142] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 74 70 59 00 00 00 08 00
[  752.033146] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 1953519872
[  752.038845] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[  752.308013] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  752.412150] usb 2-7: USB disconnect, device number 7
```

I also tried below command: `sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt`

```
$MFTMirr does not match $MFT (record 0).
Failed to mount '/dev/sda1': Input/output error
NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a
SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows
then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very
important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate
it and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g.
/dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Please see the 'dmraid' documentation
for more details.
```

I also tried running this command `lsusb -t`:

```
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/10p, 10000M
    |__ Port 6: Dev 11, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=uas, 5000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/16p, 480M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 7, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 7, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
    |__ Port 4: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 7: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 7: Dev 4, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 14: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
    |__ Port 14: Dev 5, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
```

Besides `[sdc]` I also got `[sda]` that looks okay. What is this `[sdc]` and `[sda]`?

Could anyone please help? Thanks

Comment: Please post the output of `lsusb -t` in your question. I expect it shows `Driver=uas` and it should read `Driver=usb-storage`. You might want to have a look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/525290/usb-hdd-not-found.

Comment: Hi @thecarpy, I already modified my question. Yes it gave me ```Driver=uas```. I just tried ```ntfsfix``` it looks better now, i can mount it, but the Driver is still uas. What does it mean? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you using this drive on Windows too? Have you tried the advice given by the output of command:`mount`?

`In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows then reboot into Windows twice.`

Answer (score 0):

You need to blacklist `uas` for this device. To check you have `usb-storage` as a kernel module, please issue the following: `lsmod | grep usb-storage`, if it outputs something, you have the module loaded.

1. Module is loaded

Blacklist the module for your device and reboot:

```
   $ echo options usb-storage quirks=0bc2:231a:u | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-uas.conf
   $ sudo update-initramfs -u
   $ sudo reboot
```

2. usb-storage is built-into the kernel

See this UNIX stackexchange [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/441668/debian-usb3-hdd-uas-i-o-errors).

You need to change the boot options, this depends on you boot loader, ARM kernels sometimes have usb-storage built-in. In this case, you need to change the kernel command line e.g. `/boot/armbianEnv.txt`.

This file might already have a `usbstoragequirks` entry, in which case you simply append `,<vendor_id>:<device_id>:u` to the list:

```
usbstoragequirks=0x2537:0x1066:u,0x2537:0x1068:u
usbstoragequirks=0x2537:0x1066:u,0x2537:0x1068:u,0bc2:231a:u
```

If there is none, ensure there is a `rootfstype=<some_fs>`, e.g. `rootfstype=ext4` and append this on a new line:

```
usbstoragequirks=0bc2:231a:u
```

Example file from the UNIX stackexchange answer:

```
verbosity=1
console=both
overlay_prefix=sun50i-h5
overlays=usbhost1 usbhost2
rootdev=UUID=b58048d3-ca7b-4ea6-9812-95d403fddadd
rootfstype=ext4
usbstoragequirks=0x2537:0x1066:u,0x2537:0x1068:u
```